# Is there a way to get PyCharm to warn about unused returns?

Tags: python, pycharm

Is there a way to get PyCharm to warn about unused return values?

I normally use a compiler for this purpose, but this is Python, so every time I forget to assign the output I only realise my mistake later at runtime.

Would be great if PyCharm could point this out for me. I think it knows quite often what the function return type is so it should be easy for them to add it if it doesn’t exist.

Is there a setting or do I need to hint to JetBrains?

Comment: I think the question is unclear. To me "unused return value" means the function returns a value, but the caller doesn't assign it to anything. But then you mention the function return type, and that's where you lose me. What does knowing the return type have to do with anything?

Comment: There are many "side effect" functions that return a value but the caller might not be interested in using it, e.g. a status. I know what you mean (I think) about it knowing the return type but there's no way to hint to PyCharm that "this value must be consumed"

Comment: I could always do _ = fn() I guess if I wanted pycharm to stop nagging me. Apologies if I wasn’t clear, I was just pointing out that if pycharm knows the return type then if I’m calling the function and not assigning it to something it should be a very easy warning/hint for pycharm to implement.